# Word frequency analyzer

Tags: translation, data-analysis, word-processor

I am a translator by night and would like to analyze the texts that I've previously written. Specifically, I'd like to focus the time I spend memorizing vocabulary by knowing which of the "trouble" words occur most often.

**Are there any utilities which let me do that?**

Comment: Could you include some more specifics/requirements, e.g. target OS, budget, specific functionalities you need (must-have) or like (optional)? See e.g. [here](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for some hints on "How to make a question high quality" ;) This will significantly improve your chances of good answers. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have any requirements. Just need it to spit out a list of words and their number of occurences.

Comment: What OS do you use, @emaltman? Not all programs run on all operating systems, and without that information we're kind of flying in the dark as to whether something will work for you or not.

Comment: I have regular access to all 3 big ones, that's why I didn't specify.

Comment: 3 big ones? Let me guess: Atari, AIX, and OS/360? ;) You should specify this at least in your questions text (just copy over your last comment, but please replace the "3 big ones" with their real names), so people don't have to dig through the comments to figure. And even if you don't have any additional "specific requirements", at least to me it's still unclear how e.g. "trouble words" should be recognized.

Comment: I'm not asking anything specific to be recognized. I want a list that I comb through myself and decide what I have trouble with.

Answer (score 4):

For a much more advanced tool, you can use [Wordstat](http://provalisresearch.com/products/content-analysis-software/wordstat-features/):

- non-free but 30-day trial
- tons of features, including frequency analysis on keywords, phrases, derived categories or concepts, or user-defined codes entered manually within a text:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://textalyser.net/:

- free
- online
- perform word frequency analysis:

[image]

Comment: That is beautiful. Is there a file size/word count limit that you know of?

Comment: Sorry I don't know but counting is not CPU intensive so I would be surprised if there is any tight limit. I would say the main limit is the document type supported: only .txt I think.