# Program to search for word repetitions in Word documents

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I have a rather large document containing a lot of text, so I am seeking for a tool automating the process of finding word repetitions.

**Requirements**

- Find word repetitions (which, for example, occur in the same paragraph) inside a Microsoft Word document.
- The most convenient way would probably involve a Word add-on, but other ways (e.g. programs operating on exported formats such as PDF) are also welcome.
- The repetitions should be allowed to differ in case, prefixes, suffixes, declension or in grammatical number.
  For example, the following pairs in each case should be treated as if they were the same:

  - allow, `A`llow
  - house, house`s`
  - allow, `A`llowance
  - friend, friend`'s`

  (An algorithm using a heuristic comparing the word's stems would suffice in many cases, in my opinion.)

**Optional**

- A blacklist of words (e.g. `of, the, by`) which is manageable by the user.

My request is different from a [word frequency analyzer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4266/583) insofar that I would like to be presented with word repetitions only occurring in the same paragraph or in the same specified set of lines.

Gratis software is always welcome, but I am also open to trial versions allowing me to test the program before buying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two pieces of software that might help you.

1. [Repetition Detector](http://www.repetition-detector.com/):

   - highlights close and distant repetitions,
   - is a standalone software, but once your text is in it keeps the MS Word formatting,
   - is not free ($7.40 for the licence) but you get 30 days free trial.
2. [Smart Edit](http://www.smart-edit.com/blog/):

   - shows repetitions,
   - does a whole bunch of other things like drives attention to excessive/misused punctuation, misused or mistakenly used words, etc.
   - works as Word add-in,
   - not free but has a free trial.

Maybe worth a look.

Comment: I've just tried both of them and both have their applications! **Repetition Detector seems to be the perfect match for highlighting neighbored repetitions in color**. SmartEdit (both the standalone and the Word add-in version) seems to disregard this locality, e.g. it says that I used "foo" X times across the document, but if these occurrences are far away from each other, then this is something I do not care about. However, **SmartEdit displays other useful information, such as used adverbs, possibly misused words and possible redundancies (e.g. "could possibly")**.