# Program to search for word repetitions in text documents

Tags: libreoffice

Similar to *ComFreeks* question on a [Program to search for word repetitions in Word documents](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11420/185), I'm looking for the very same – with just a slight difference: it should come as a plugin for *LibreOffice* / *OpenOffice.* Document format (`.odt`, `.doc`, etc) shouldn't really matter, as they are dealt with transparently by the program (if it does matter, it should at least support `.odt`).

To save you from having to read the other question for requirements, I'll copy-paste from there (site license permits: BY-SA means I've got to name the author (ComFreek) and use the same license, which both fits), so here we go:

- **Find word repetitions** (which, for example, occur in the same paragraph).
  More specifically: which occur that close to each other that a teacher would have marked them "repetition" in an essay you wrote, or would "hurt the eye" of the reader – which usually is "the same sentence/paragraph" or "distance less than X words".
- Other than ComFreeks requirements, it **must work from within the office program on the original document**, so I don't need to switch between different apps for correction (and also immediately see what no longer remains to be corrected)
- The **repetitions should be allowed to differ in case, prefixes, suffixes, declension or in grammatical number** – so e.g. "allow" and "Allow", "friend" and "friends", "eat" and "eaten" should count as pairs of repetition
- **Must support German language** (English would be nice-to-have, but is not really required)
- a user-manageable **"blacklist" of words to ignore** (e.g. articles like "the") **should be included.** Not a show-stopper if it isn't, but to me rather a "strong wish".
- optionally, but really nice-to-have: the ability to "ignore this" for a given pair (so it's no longer marked a repetition until I run the check again freshly)
- optionally and nice-to-have: integrate the "Thesaurus" feature for word replacement. This is of minor importance, as it could be achieved via standard functionality as well (highlighting the word and invoke the built-in Thesaurus).

So basically, it should either work similar to the spell-checker when triggered manually (mark-and-replace), the "check while you type" (underlining errors), or both.

Being a plugin/addon to *LibreOffice* / *OpenOffice* I'd expect it not to be OS dependent – but if it is, it ***must*** run on Linux at least. Cross-platform welcome.

Comment: With some modifications, this could make a nice [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) challenge

Comment: I'm not familiar with *Code Golf* (and how specifically that SE site works) – but I don't mind if you made a challenge out of it, proposing the results as answer here :)

Comment: I don't have a direct answer but this seems like something that could be done roughly using VBA in word, also something similar to what a translator would use, so maybe that helps you in the direction of your search. The German aspect of it could be tricky for suffixes, declension etc. as nouns vary more between cases and plurals than is the case in English.

Comment: [AuthorSupportTool](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/authorsupporttool) has a "word repitition tool". (I am posting this as a comment, so that the [idea doesn't get lost](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17640737#17640737).)

Comment: @user16583 though there's something similar to VBA in LibreOffice/OpenOffice as well, I'm not looking to write that up myself ;) Moreover, as you already pointed out, that might need support from a dictionary or the like; it might use the ones installed for it. Thanks for the pointer; that might be something the addons probably use.

Comment: Thanks, @ComFreek, for "anchoring" it here! As a small abstract: it might need to be checked first if that "word repetition tool" doesn't mean "macro expander", as the two of us figured in chat.